# How to setup redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Vue.js app?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ssl, https, nuxt.js

Trying this nuxt.config.js below, but nothing works. App is available only by "https" but not "http".  What I'm doing wrong?

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
import redirectSSL from 'redirect-ssl'

require('dotenv').config()
const client = require('./plugins/contentful')

export default {
  serverMiddleware: ["redirect-ssl"],
  target: 'server',
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 443,
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'key.pem')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'cert.pem'))
    }
  },
      
// some other code there ...
      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to redirect the Requests directly in the webservers configuration (Nginx / Apache2)

Or you need a second http server listen on port 80,but I never did that
(well I cannot coment under you post because of missing reputation)